# Django how to write queryset for get all admin user and use them in signals as receiver

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My purpose of using django signals is notify every admin when any author create new blog post. So I want to use all admin as a receiver and the only author who creating the blog post will be sender. currently I am using this `User.objects.get(username='jhone' )#jhone is an admin user` queryset for set receiver specific admin user. How to call all admin user and make theme all as receiver. here is my code:

**#models.py**

```
#using notifications model for signals 
class Notifications(models.Model):

    blog = models.ForeignKey('blog.Blog',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    blogcomment = models.ForeignKey('blog.BlogComment',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)

    NOTIFICATION_TYPES = (('New Comment','New Comment'),('Comment Approved','Comment Approved'), ('Comment Rejected','Comment Rejected'),('pending post','pending post'),('post approved','post approved'),('post rejected','post rejected'))

    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_from_user")

    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_to_user")
    #others fields...... 

class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=100)
    #others fields....
    def blog_notify(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        blog = instance
        blog_title = blog.title
        sender = blog.author
        receiver  =  User.objects.get(username='jhone')

        if sender == blog.author and blog.is_published == "published":
         notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender,receiver =receiver ,text_preview = blog_title[:250], notification_type="post approved")
         notify.save()

post_save.connect(Blog.blog_notify, sender=Blog)
```

I also tried few queryset for set all admin user as receiver but non of theme didn't work.

```
receiver  = User.objects.all().filter(is_superuser=True)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<User: Jhone>, <User: admin1>, <User: admin2>]>": "Notifications.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

for using `User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)` this queryset.

I also tried this

```
receiver  =  User.objects.all().get(is_superuser=True)
```

and getting this error

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /blog-admin/approve-blog-post/tusar-post2/
get() returned more than one User -- it returned 3!
```

any idea how to pass right queryset for set all admin user as receiver???

Comment: Why are you using `for receiver in user:`? My answer was with `for receiver in receivers:`

Comment: becasue I am using variable user in my code instead of receivers

Comment: bdbd here is the line ` user =   User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)`

Comment: Can you show that line. Also can you fix the indentation? My answer was using `bulk_create`, but your is using `create`, and using `notification` which is a list! This is very different from the answer I gave. Can you try using that exact code?

Comment: bdbd see the updated question. I added full code

Comment: Still wrong. I used `bulk_create` outside of the for loop. You used `create` inside the for loop. Can you try copy-pasting it exactly?

Comment: bdbd I need to be use `create` outside of for loop. right?? I tried but still now same result

Comment: `bulk_create` and not `create`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235041/discussion-between-boyenec-and-bdbd).

Comment: bdbd the problem is solved now but my author seeing multiple notifications in my html template. If I have three admin then it creating three notification which is fine but my author is getting three notification. how to show only one notification to author ?

Comment: This is a new question so it would be better to create a new one rather than mess up this whole thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through all the admins and create the `Notifications` one by one like so:

```
def blog_notify(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    blog = instance
    blog_title = blog.title
    sender = blog.author
    receivers = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)

    if not (sender == blog.author and blog.is_published == "published"):
        return

    notifications = []

    for receiver in receivers:
        notifications.append(Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, receiver=receiver, text_preview=blog_title[:250], notification_type="post approved"))

    Notifications.objects.bulk_create(notifications)
```

Just note that if `Notifications` model is sending signals, then you can't use `bulk_create`. In that case just create them one by one.

Comment: bdbd Thanks. What if I have large group of user? So it will be better send all notification at onece instead of sending one by one. Is there any way I can send them at once instead of sending one by one ?

Comment: It depends. Can you update your question on how you actually send? My answer is about how to put them all in the `Notifications` model in one update.

Comment: Bdbd basically notification send from the blog model when any new blog post creating. I didn't add the views.py code in my question because it's using only for showing notification in my html template. Do you want to see my views.py code ???

Comment: The `bulk_create` will create/send the `Notifications` in one go. If that's not enough, then please show your views.py

Comment: bdbd no notification creating after using your code

Comment: Can you debug and see which code is not being executed? Maybe the `if` gets triggered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235052/discussion-between-boyenec-and-bdbd).